# Accessing google authenticator with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, google-2fa

I am trying to automate a sign in process to a website, after i enter the login details i am asked to enter the 2FA code every time even on my regular browser, is there a way i can get puppeteer to access my chrome extensions so it can read the 2FA code?

Comment: Have you considered using https://mswjs.io/ to mock your API endpoints for your test? That would allow you to simply enter any 2FA code, and return an arbitrary response with your mock to test different scenarios.

Comment: Try: https://dev.to/ajaykumbhare/load-chrome-extensions-in-puppeteer-4fk0